# excel how to paste formula from column to row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, copy-paste

I want copy the column A formula into row 1 like this :

```
   A                 B                C               D
```

1   ='sheet1'!B2.......='sheet1'!B3............='sheet1'!B4............='sheet1'!B5

2   ='sheet1'!B3

3   ='sheet1'!B4

4   ='sheet1'!B5

5   ='sheet1'!B6

but when I copy the formula from column A to B, the cell(B1) will become ='sheet1'!C3, are there any way transpose the formula without change one by one?

Comment: please accept my answer if it helped you out mate

Answer (score 0):

When you right-click (to paste your copied selection), it comes up with a `Paste Special` option. Click this and select `Transpose`. This should do it for you.
And changing the B3 (in your formula) to $B3 should stop it changing the formula

Comment: I think there are more than 5 rows in his sheet. If you have to change them all from B3 to $B$3 this is a pain.

Comment: hey!! it works, I change B3 into $B3 and it works out~ thanks ~